# how to obtain license key for here maps api

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not able to find the license key from here maps. I have my app ID and app Code already but not the license key.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(yourAppID, appCode: yourAppCode, licenseKey: yourLicenseKey)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you checked their docs? Is it a paid service?

Comment: Yeah I did and I am not able to find it. Apparently, their docs don't say anything about license key and I guess I don't need it anymore to use their API. Thanks for the initiative though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Starter SDKs there is no License key available.

You need to register for Premium SDK

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing! That really should be made more clear from the dev console.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the API key from [here](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks) after you sign up.

When you sign up, A project will be created for you.

You will need to add your bundle id and generate the API key from the project settings(Project Page).

Also, when you create the app you will also receive and email which guides you through the steps.

Comment: I was asking about license key. I have the api key but thanks for the help. I appreciate that.